# How to import "javax.xml.validation"

Tags: android, xml, api, validation, sdk

I am trying to import "javax.xml.validation" to valid some XML I am downloading, and eclipse throws an error. I am using the 1.5 API, was it even implemented then? If so what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the JAXP implementation that comes with the Sun JDK - it's buggy. Use Xerces from Apache: it's more up-to-date with the various W3C specs, and it's far more reliable.